# Toggling classes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

When I click on a thumbnail (`.framesButton`) it slides open a panel which is fine. I just want it to also add a class (`.frameSelected`) which adds the background with the little black triangle to the `img`'s parent `<li>` which kind of works at the moment if I click on and off the same thumbnail as I'm just toggling. But if I click on another thumbnail whilst the slide panel is still open I get a triangle but with a closed panel. You can see here:

http://oaeyewear.4pixels.co.uk/brands.html

My code so far is:

```
$('.framesButton').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('frameSelected');
      $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('frameSelected');
});
```

Unfortunately my jQuery is still to basic for me to translate what I want into code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always toggling the visibility of the container in

```
$(".framesButton").click(function(){  
    $(".lensesDetail").slideToggle('slow');  
});
```

no matter whether the same thumbnail is clicked or not.

A solution would be to test whether the clicked element is the previously clicked one or not, which you can do by testing whether its parent has the class `frameSelected`. If yes, hide the container, if not, leave it open or open it.

Combine both click event handlers to:

```
$('.framesButton').click(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();

    if ($parent.hasClass('frameSelected')) {
        // toggle visibility of container
        $('.lensesDetail').slideToggle('slow');  
    }
    else {
        // show the container - won't do anything if already open
        $('.lensesDetail').slideDown('slow');
    }

    $parent.toggleClass('frameSelected')
        .siblings('.frameSelected').removeClass('frameSelected');
});
```

---

The solution depends on how exactly you are populating the  `.lensesDetail` element with information, i.e. whether you have one for each thumbnail or one for each row or one for the whole list.
You will have to adjust the above solution once you figured this out.

Comment: Thanks Felix, that works perfectly and I now understand hasClass and how to use it :) The '.lensesDetail' panel will change depending on clicking each thumb if the panel is already open. I haven't decided how to animate this so the user knows it's changed. A slide would be lovely but maybe beyond my ability so maybe I'll just fade out and fade in.

Answer (score 0):

In short and simple just do this:

```
$(".framesButton").click(function(){  
    $(".lensesDetail").slideUp('slow',function(){
       $(".lensesDetail").slideDown('slow');
    });  
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('frameSelected');
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('frameSelected');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jai. Tried that but with no luck. I think the second line would be slideDown anyway. But I will have a play with it as I'm learning from everything I do and everyones quick responses.